# Checking Alphabetic derived property in Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I've tried `myStr.matches("^[\\p{Alphabetic}]+$")` but this causes a PatternSyntaxException with message `Unknown character property name {Alphabetic} near index 15`.

I believe `\p{Alpha}` only matches ASCII characters, whereas I want to match all unicode characters with the derived Alphabetic property.

`unichars` seems to be able to get a list which I could theoretically check against, but this seems like a hack.

How can I check if the [Alphabetic property](http://www.unicode.org/Public/5.1.0/ucd/UCD.html#Alphabetic) applies using a regular expression, with Java?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean but there are not a word Alphabitic you have to use Alpha instead `myStr.matches("^[\\p{Alpha}]+$")` is that what you mean?

Comment: No, please read the second sentence of the question. `\p{Alpha}` is *not* what I want - try `"ä".matches("^[\\p{Alpha}]+$")` to see why, it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in [the API for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the correct name is `IsAlphabetic`.

E.g.

```
"ä".matches("^[\\p{IsAlphabetic}]+$")
```